# Google Drive: read-only without authorisation on external site

Tags: file, authorization, google-drive-api, readonly

I have an idea to use Google Drive as a no-database CMS, where clients would put their files in specific folders which is then accessed on an external site. For example, they would upload an image and a script would iterate through that folder for all image files and display them accordingly as a gallery.

I'm very new to the Drive SDK (and APIs in general) and I'm trying to get my head around if it's even possible to make the files read-only without requiring an authorisation for the end user? My initial attempts have required me to authenticate whenever I load the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is be possible for a third party app to authorize requests without an access token. You can make requests from an allowed referrer/IP with an API key.

https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys

Then, you should be allowed to GET the following public file:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1T_fVTiyyBVnfYKd_3gZzVfxqU5NbOhIlEG0nyReYh9w?key=[yourKey]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Burcu, although I'm getting really confused on Google's documentation. From trying out a couple of methods, it seems I can't request to view a list of files (from a specific folder) without the need of authorisation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list. Not sure I've interpreted this correctly - the SDK requires authentication but the API does not?

Comment: In order to access to a user's account such as listing the files, you need an access token. For to retrieve public file detail, you can use an API key.

Comment: Ok. Any ideas on where to start using this approach?

Comment: Wait, I take it you mean I need to authorize to access the user's account? Or would I be able to browse his/her files using only an API key?

Comment: You cannot query user's files without an access token even the files you want to query are public. Otherwise, how we would know whose files you are querying for. User id is not a part of the /files resource. We're resolving the user by the access token, so you need to implement one of the OAuth 2.0 flows.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I just don't see a reason why not since it's possible to link directly to single sources anyway by publishing for the web in the share options for each folder. That would essentially open up for the same kind of "exploits", if this was the case? Note that I'm referring only to files that the user him-/herself has chosen to share publicly.